# How to pass flag variable into http.Get in Golang

Tags: go, flags

I have a block of code which hardcodes the URL required for REST API that I am consuming. What I would like to do is, use the two flags to dynamically generate the URL. For example, something to the effect of:

`response, err := http.Get("https://swapi.co/api/%s/1", resourcePtr)`

My current code is as follows:

```
func main() {

    resourcePtr := flag.String("resource", "", "a string")
    idPtr := flag.Int("id", 1, "an int")

    flag.Parse()

    response, err := http.Get("https://swapi.co/api/planets/1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("HTTP request failed with error %s\n", err)
    } else {
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        fmt.Println(string(data))
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `fmt.Sprintf` (https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) is for.

```
response, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://swapi.co/api/%s/1", resourcePtr))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!